# Finding cause of memory error when using AWS glue with S3

Tags: amazon-web-services, apache-spark, amazon-s3, aws-lambda, aws-glue

I am using AWS Lambda and AWS Glue in conjunction to unzip large files (up to 150GB) that are stored in S3. The job works fine on small files (1-2GB) however larger files failed with "Memory Error". I can't find any information about a memory error in relevant Cloudwatch logs and there is nothing showing up in the metrics section built into Glue. How can I determine where my issue is coming from and what can I do to solve it?
Thank you

PS. My Glue job is using spark running on Python 3

Comment: What is the compression codec that you are using ?

Answer (score -1):

You need to look at what spark is actually doing and in what stage the job failed in.  In spark there's two different types of operators.  ones the require bringing all records into memory and ones that can be streamed so that only one record is in memory (slightly simplified).  Chances are its the not reading the CSV thats causing the failure but the next step after it.  The spark history server will give you more info on whats going on in the sql tab, for manually print out the query plan with a dataframe.explain().

I suspect you'll be able to side step this by adding a manual dataframe.repartition(400) before whatever else you are doing.

Also IMO its bad practice to create CSVs that large.  either go with sets of reasonably sized CSVs or use a format that allows for multiple parallel readers such as parquet.